Laravel Sanctum tokem mismatch issue
I am using laravel/sanctum on my backend, and nuxt 3 app on frontend.
When I restart my container, my laravel app start giving 419 error on api calls because csrf token mismatch.
A quick resolution is we clear cookies from browser and refresh nuxt app, it would bring new csrf token, and then backend start catering api calls.
But we can not ask our users to clear there cookies. Is there any way, we can solve this issue?
